# How do I stop a syscall from blocking indefinitely in Go?

Tags: go, linux-kernel, filesystems, system-calls

I'm trying to do something very simple in Go: open a file. However, the file system that contains the files I'd like to open seems to have a few bugs (ntfs-3g). My program, among other things, opens up every file in the filesystem and hashes it.

To open a file, I first tried:

```golang
os.Open(path) // equivalent to:
os.OpenFile(path, os.O_RDONLY, 0)
```

After a long time, the hashing of files stopped. I examined the goroutines and they looked like this:

```
^\SIGQUIT: quit
PC=0x403aac m=0 sigcode=128

goroutine 20 [syscall, 130 minutes]:
syscall.Syscall6(0xc000136000?, 0xac?, 0x7fa25a5024e8?, 0xb0?, 0x1?, 0xc00018dc60?, 0x416153?)
        /usr/local/go/src/syscall/syscall_linux.go:91 +0x36 fp=0xc00018dbe0 sp=0xc00018db58 pc=0x472016
syscall.openat(0x0?, {0xc000136000?, 0x415b2b?}, 0x761e58?, 0x0)
        /usr/local/go/src/syscall/zsyscall_linux_amd64.go:83 +0x94 fp=0xc00018dc58 sp=0xc00018dbe0 pc=0x46fff4
syscall.Open(...)
        /usr/local/go/src/syscall/syscall_linux.go:272
os.openFileNolog({0xc000136000, 0xac}, 0x0, 0x0)
        /usr/local/go/src/os/file_unix.go:226 +0x9b fp=0xc00018dca0 sp=0xc00018dc58 pc=0x49dc7b
os.OpenFile({0xc000136000, 0xac}, 0x0, 0x40d648?)
        /usr/local/go/src/os/file.go:326 +0x45 fp=0xc00018dcd8 sp=0xc00018dca0 pc=0x49c2e5
os.Open(...)
        /usr/local/go/src/os/file.go:306
github.com/project/mymodule.HashFile({0xc000136000?, 0xac?})
```

Every goroutine was blocked like this (for over two hours!). I tried adding `unix.O_NONBLOCK`:

```
os.OpenFile(path, os.O_RDONLY|unix.O_NONBLOCK, 0)
```

In spite of my parameter specifying not to block, it keeps blocking (I think this might be a bad idea for other reasons, because it makes all subsequent reads non-blocking and I'm not sure if Go would handle that correctly, but that's beside the point because it didn't fix my problem).

I'm aware that this is really the filesystem's problem, but it surprises me that it's so hard to find a workaround, especially with so many potentially unreliable filesystems like NFS or SSHFS in the wild these days. The workaround I found was this:

```golang
func HashFile(path string) ([]byte, []byte, error) {
    alarm := time.NewTimer(10 * time.Second)
    defer alarm.Stop()

    fileChan := make(chan *os.File)
    errChan := make(chan error)

    go func() {
        f, err := os.OpenFile(path, os.O_RDONLY|unix.O_NONBLOCK, 0) // or without O_NONBLOCK
        if err != nil {
            errChan <- err
            return
        }
        fileChan <- f
    }()

    var f *os.File
    var err error

    select {
    case f = <-fileChan:
        defer f.Close()
    case err = <-errChan:
        logrus.Warnf("failed to open %v: %v", path, err)
        return nil, nil, err
    case <-alarm.C:
        logrus.Errorf("timeout while opening %v", path)
        return nil, nil, fmt.Errorf("timeout")
    }

    sha1Hasher := sha1.New()
    md5Hasher := md5.New()
    sink := io.MultiWriter(sha1Hasher, md5Hasher)
    if _, err := io.Copy(sink, f); err != nil {
        return nil, nil, err
    }

    return sha1Hasher.Sum(nil), md5Hasher.Sum(nil), nil
}
```

I could also retry, which (inexplicably) works some of the time.

So, this at least gets my program to avoid a deadlock. But, there's another problem: now there will be a large number of blocked goroutines which are all in the middle of a syscall. There's some sort of limit to that. That means I can't use this workaround indefinitely; I have to bounce the program periodically.

Is there a better way?

Comment: If the syscall is blocking indefinitely even with `O_NONBLOCK`, there's nothing you can really do in Go to change that. Go just makes the syscall and then parks the thread until it returns. If it never returns, it never returns.